# How do you get POSTed value from dynamically populated dropdownlist without the use of UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Web Form dependent on a Master Page, that contains a simple Form like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtValue"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProduct" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirm" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_OnClick" />
```

on Page_Load I dynamically populate the DropDownList with values:

```
foreach(var product in products)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem(product.Nazev, product.ProductId.ToString());
    ddlProduct.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Now .. normally if the DropDownList was populated statically, I would go with this, to get my selected value out of it:

```
protected void btnConfirm_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedProduct = ddlProduct.SelectedValue;
}
```

But this is a no-go in this situation. Hence I try to directly get the selected value from POSTed parameters with one of those approaches (which are in fact practically the same):

```
protected void btnConfirm_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedProduct = Request.Form.Get(ddlProdukt.ClientID);
    string selectedProduct2 = Request.Params[ddlProdukt.ClientID];
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I debug it, the actual "id/name" of the DropDownList in the POSTed Form (Request.Params) is:

"ctl00$MainContent$ddlProdukt"

whereas the ClientId my approach gives me is:

"ctl00_MainContent_ddlProdukt"

I can't figure out, why does it replace '_' for '$' in the ID of my DDL control.. It seems to be such a trivial thing. There should be a better way to find out the right ID, than replacing the character, right?

Is there some other way I should "look/ask" for the selected value?

*Take into account, that I'am not looking for a solution with an UpdatePanel. I know, that using an UpdatePanel would result in the DDL value being sucessfully selected after the Postback, but that is NOT the answer I'm looking for here.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Why is that a no-go? You can still get the values with `SelectedValue`. you only need to bind data to the DDL in an `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: VDWWD: Care to show me an example how? If I try, I encounter the same problem as mentioned above -> being unable to get the correct ID of my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need to use the `Request.Form.Get` or `Request.Params` you should call it on `ddlProdukt.UniqueID` as it's separator is '$' versus '_' on the `.ClientID`

Comment: I knew there muset be some easy solution to this silly problem. I must be an idiot to miss that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As requested an example. This code and the `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>` are on the aspx page, not the Master.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind data not here
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //but inside the ispostback check
        ddlProduct.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "1"));
        ddlProduct.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2", "2"));
        ddlProduct.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3", "3"));
        ddlProduct.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = ddlProduct.SelectedValue;
}
```